# Background Video Align

Tags: html, css, video, background

Can someone help me to get this Video to algin top?

http://mystery-house.de/final/index.html

```css
video#bgvid{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
width:1440px;
height:auto;
z-index:-100;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(../images/video.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 <video autoplay loop poster="http://mystery-house.de/final/_files/video/video.jpg" id="bgvid">
<source src="http://mystery-house.de/final/_files/video/mysteryhouse.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Comment: whats the problem? it is aligned to the top?

Comment: Hi Rachel - on my Computer it looks like this: http://mystery-house.de/final/topbug.jpg

Comment: how big is your computer?

Comment: how does this look on your computer http://output.jsbin.com/siruvuhuqo

Comment: Perfect! :) So its the rest of my Code making Problems? :/ or ... background-size: cover!important; background-position: top left; ... ok, i try  a little :D thx

Comment: its your transform thats the problem.

Comment: Oh! I was just watching the comments! Thx! Didnt see the answers :)

Comment: grand, just keep a lookout cos people tend to answer quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transform is causing a problem on bigger screens. you should add media queries to deal with it.

```
  @media screen and min-width:1440px{take the transform out etc.}
```

Comment: or you could just reduce the transform

Answer (score 0):

Your transform style is set to 50%. When I delete it the background image covers the area.

If you want to size a background image you can specify width in background-size style.  You can also try background-position to align a background to the "top center"